# using style in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles, groupbox

In my application I use the ShinyBlue.xaml resource dictionary which has this code for the `GroupBox` control:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="6" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4"
                            Background="{DynamicResource LightBrush}"
                            CornerRadius="4,4,4,4"
                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

   </Style>
```

These style common for all app. But in one of the forms I want to change the `Background` to `Transparent`. I want override only the `Background` property but it doesn't work

```
<Style TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GroupBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

The code above does not work properly.

How can I change the `GroupBox` `Background` in a specific form ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ControlTemplate does not actually use the Background property, but it assigns a concrete value to the Border's Background property, namely `{DynamicResource LightBrush}`. Now, when you set the Background property locally, this has no effect because the Border still uses the `LightBrush` resource.
You have to use `TemplateBinding`s to make the correct Background appear in your control like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <!-- set default value for the template -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource LightBrush}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="6" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- Note the new TemplateBinding for the Background property! -->
                    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

This way, the Border actually uses the GroupBox's Background property. To make it use the `LightBrush` by default, I have added a Setter which defines the default value for the Background property. This value can then be overridden by locally setting the Background property on your GroupBox.